# Problems after remove network-manager

Tags: network-manager, crash, software-uninstall

I've decided to test **wicd** in my notebook, so I uninstall **network-manger**. Now, Ubuntu doesn't open the configuration window anymore, even after I re-installed network-manager.

Comment: What configuration window are you referring to, exactly? what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: My version is Ubuntu 18.04 and the configuration window is where you see wifi, bluetooth, change wallpaper, screen resolution....

Comment: Well uninstalling `network-manager` will likely have removed a bunch of dependent packages such as `network-manager-gnome` - did you reinstall these also?

Comment: I tried this, I re-installed network_manager-gnome, but this doesn't work for me. When I click in `wifi configuration` the window still doesn't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing NetworkManager just installs the application in the background. Not the indicator. And it doesn't RUN either of them. Also, NetworkManager creates configuration files on-the-fly.

So, you need to make sure ...

```
*) NetworkManager is installed (apt-get install)
*) the indicator applet is installed (apt-get install)
*) NetworkManager is being started (systemctl start NetworkMananger)
*) check if it runs without errors (systemctl status NetworkMananger)
*) if yes, NetworkManager is being started upon reboot (systemctl enable NetworkMananger)
*) the indicator applet is being started (for example in your startup apps for your GUI ... depending on your GUI, check your control center)
```

And given all that happend, and another network application has not been in the way of NetworkMananger, you might or might not find basic settings in your list. For example for your wired connection.

BTW, just to have said it, in the applet you might find two setting like enable network and enable WIFI or similar label (I have it in a different language, so I don't know the exact english labels). With those disabled you won't get WIFI connections either.

If you don't have configuration files at this point, you can either create it by hand. Or another option is, given your driver and adapter are working, you should now have a list of available networks in your applet. Click on the wireless network you want to connect with will ask your for the password and create a basic configuration file, which afterwards you can edit.

And referring to WICD, if you are trying to go back to simpler days and make it simple and lightweight, you can also skip WICD and go directly to wpa supplicant and dhcpcd. Because that is what's really needed to connect. Everything else is just a helper ;)

Connecting would look approx like this:

`ip link`
(find out the label of your network adapter, example: wlan0)
`ip link set dev wlan0 up`
(activate the adapter)
`wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "WIFI Name - SSID" "Password") &`
(connect to your WIFI)
`dhcpcd wlan0 &`
(get a dynamic IP from your modem/router)

Of course you would have to make sure your nameserver is set correctly in your /etc/resolv.conf.

And to disconnect you just:
`ip link set dev wlan0 down`

Comment: thanks, but the problem was that when i remove network-manager, i accidentally remove `gnome-control-center` too. I reinstalled it and everything works fun now.